# Metric spaces and sets.

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Hello I was given a take home true or false questionnaire to study for a final but was not given the answer key and was hoping you could help me out with this question:

In a metric space, every open set is the union of countably many closed sets.

I marked this as False.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is actually true. Let $X$ be the space, and let $U$ be the open set in question. If $U=X$ then of course $U$ is closed, so it’s certainly the union of countably many closed sets. Suppose, then, that $U\ne X$, and let $F=X\setminus U\ne\varnothing$. For each $x\in U$ let

$$f(x)=\inf\{d(x,y):y\in F\}\;;$$

because $F$ is closed, $f(x)>0$ for each $x\in U$. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $C_n=\{x\in U:f(x)\ge 2^{-n}\}$; $f$ is continuous, so each $C_n$ is closed, and $U=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}C_n$.

Comment: how you know the inf exists in an not complete metric space ?

Comment: @Dominic: It’s the infimum of a set of positive real numbers, and $\Bbb R$ **is** complete. Note that I’m not saying that there is a point $y\in F$ such that $f(x)=d(x,y)$.

Comment: oh right that was a stupid one